# Supervisor running daemons from /etc/init.d

Tags: supervisord

Inside supervisord.conf is this

```
[program:ElasticSearch]
command=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/log/ES-out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/ES-err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

when i execute

```
/etc/init.d/supervisor restart
```

It runs smoothly , but the logs look like this

```
2016-11-23 14:39:38,873 INFO supervisord started with pid 2737
2016-11-23 14:39:39,875 INFO spawned: 'ElasticSearch' with pid 2758
2016-11-23 14:39:39,908 INFO exited: ElasticSearch (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-11-23 14:39:40,910 INFO spawned: 'ElasticSearch' with pid 2805
2016-11-23 14:39:40,934 INFO exited: ElasticSearch (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-11-23 14:39:42,937 INFO spawned: 'ElasticSearch' with pid 2822
2016-11-23 14:39:42,967 INFO exited: ElasticSearch (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-11-23 14:39:45,971 INFO spawned: 'ElasticSearch' with pid 2860
2016-11-23 14:39:45,991 INFO exited: ElasticSearch (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-11-23 14:39:46,992 INFO gave up: ElasticSearch entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Why that? How can i run app from /etc/init.d like this?

Comment: Does the elasticsearch error log show anything?

Comment: Starting elasticsearch (via systemctl): elasticsearch.service.
You need root privileges to run this script
Starting elasticsearch (via systemctl): elasticsearch.service.

it says this... but its 4 times... notice the message on the logs.. its 4 times error. 

So there is a privilege error i guess

Comment: Im sudo when i /etc/init.d/supervisor restart